# Homomorphic image of a CLT-group

Tags: finite-groups, noncommutative-algebra

I know that homomorphic image of CLT-group (converse Lagrange's theorem) is not CLT. Is there any reference to know when a homomorphic image of CLT-group is CLT group?

Comment: Are you looking for conditions on the homomorphism, or are you looking for references on CLT groups all of whose quotients are also CLT groups?

Comment: Actually I am looking for references on CLT groups all of whose quotients are also CLT groups. Is there any restriction on homomorphism for which image would be CLT?